# It is related to a type of mathematics game

Tags: formation-of-numbers, calculation-puzzle

Start with two digits from $1\dots9$ to form a $2$-digit number.

Multiply this number by a single digit from $1\dots9$.

Add the result to another two digit number from $1\dots9$, and calculate the result.

**You can only use each digit once.**

In other words:

How can the digits                  $\, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \,$
all be assigned to the placeholders $\, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i \,$
so that $\, ab \times c = fg\,$ and $\, fg + de = hi \,$?

<sup>($ab$, $de$, $fg$ and $hi$ are explicit two-digit numbers, not products.)</sup>

Comment: This isn't a puzzle or riddle or question, just a list of arbitrary instructions.

Comment: Are you trying to ask us to find a number `ab` which multiplied by `c` gives `de` to which is added `fg` giving a final result `hi`, such that each of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `h` and `i` are unique non-zero digits?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming I understand what you are asking, the answer is:

> $17 \times 4 \rightarrow 68 + 25 \rightarrow 93$

Comment: Thanks for the edit @gentlepurplerain - it has prompted me to print out the formatting help page.  (Now just have to find time to read it!)

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you mean that both the intermediate result ($ab*c$) and the result ($ab*c+de$) are included in the usage of digits condition.*

Then

> the only answer is $17\times4=68\rightarrow68+25=93$

---

*Assuming you mean that the result ($ab*c+de$) is included in the usage of digits condition.*

Then

> there are $447$ valid answers, including $3$ which only use $[1,7]$:\begin{align}14\times2+37&=65\\14\times3+25&=67\\16\times2+43&=75\end{align}

Because

> These are all of them:
>
> ```
> 12 * 3 + 49 =  85
> 12 * 3 + 58 =  94
> 12 * 4 + 37 =  85
> 12 * 4 + 39 =  87
> 13 * 2 + 49 =  75
> 13 * 2 + 68 =  94
> 13 * 4 + 26 =  78
> 13 * 5 + 24 =  89
> 31 * 6 + 89 = 275
> 31 * 7 + 48 = 265
> 31 * 8 + 47 = 295
> 14 * 2 + 37 =  65
> 14 * 2 + 39 =  67
> 14 * 2 + 65 =  93
> 14 * 2 + 59 =  87
> 14 * 2 + 67 =  95
> 14 * 3 + 25 =  67
> 14 * 3 + 27 =  69
> 14 * 3 + 56 =  98
> 41 * 5 + 68 = 273
> 41 * 6 + 39 = 285
> 41 * 6 + 79 = 325
> 41 * 7 + 82 = 369
> 41 * 7 + 95 = 382
> 41 * 8 + 29 = 357
> 41 * 8 + 67 = 395
> 15 * 3 + 24 =  69
> 15 * 3 + 42 =  87
> 15 * 3 + 29 =  74
> 15 * 3 + 47 =  92
> 51 * 4 + 69 = 273
> 51 * 4 + 79 = 283
> 51 * 7 + 82 = 439
> 51 * 7 + 29 = 386
> 51 * 8 + 29 = 437
> 51 * 9 + 27 = 486
> 16 * 2 + 43 =  75
> 16 * 2 + 57 =  89
> 16 * 3 + 47 =  95
> 61 * 3 + 95 = 278
> 16 * 4 + 23 =  87
> 16 * 4 + 25 =  89
> 61 * 4 + 35 = 279
> 61 * 4 + 53 = 297
> 61 * 4 + 85 = 329
> 61 * 5 + 87 = 392
> 61 * 5 + 79 = 384
> 61 * 7 + 32 = 459
> 61 * 8 + 39 = 527
> 61 * 8 + 49 = 537
> 61 * 9 + 24 = 573
> 17 * 2 + 34 =  68
> 17 * 2 + 35 =  69
> 17 * 2 + 64 =  98
> 17 * 2 + 49 =  83
> 17 * 3 + 45 =  96
> 71 * 3 + 46 = 259
> 17 * 4 + 25 =  93
> 17 * 4 + 28 =  96
> 71 * 4 + 85 = 369
> 71 * 4 + 68 = 352
> 71 * 5 + 29 = 384
> 71 * 5 + 68 = 423
> 71 * 6 + 32 = 458
> 71 * 6 + 98 = 524
> 71 * 8 + 26 = 594
> 71 * 9 + 43 = 682
> 18 * 2 + 43 =  79
> 18 * 2 + 39 =  75
> 18 * 2 + 57 =  93
> 18 * 3 + 42 =  96
> 18 * 3 + 25 =  79
> 81 * 3 + 54 = 297
> 18 * 4 + 23 =  95
> 18 * 4 + 25 =  97
> 81 * 4 + 52 = 376
> 81 * 4 + 72 = 396
> 81 * 6 + 43 = 529
> 81 * 7 + 26 = 593
> 81 * 9 + 24 = 753
> 81 * 9 + 35 = 764
> 18 * 9 + 74 = 236
> 19 * 2 + 36 =  74
> 19 * 2 + 38 =  76
> 19 * 2 + 45 =  83
> 19 * 2 + 47 =  85
> 19 * 3 + 27 =  84
> 91 * 5 + 23 = 478
> 91 * 5 + 32 = 487
> 91 * 6 + 32 = 578
> 91 * 6 + 28 = 574
> 91 * 7 + 45 = 682
> 91 * 8 + 26 = 754
> 91 * 8 + 34 = 762
> 23 * 1 + 45 =  68
> 32 * 1 + 54 =  86
> 23 * 1 + 64 =  87
> 32 * 1 + 46 =  78
> 23 * 1 + 56 =  79
> 32 * 1 + 65 =  97
> 23 * 1 + 75 =  98
> 32 * 1 + 57 =  89
> 23 * 4 + 95 = 187
> 32 * 4 + 59 = 187
> 23 * 4 + 67 = 159
> 32 * 4 + 67 = 195
> 23 * 5 + 64 = 179
> 23 * 5 + 74 = 189
> 23 * 5 + 69 = 184
> 23 * 6 + 47 = 185
> 23 * 6 + 49 = 187
> 24 * 1 + 63 =  87
> 42 * 1 + 36 =  78
> 24 * 1 + 65 =  89
> 42 * 1 + 56 =  98
> 24 * 1 + 59 =  83
> 24 * 3 + 15 =  87
> 24 * 3 + 17 =  89
> 24 * 3 + 95 = 167
> 24 * 3 + 87 = 159
> 24 * 6 + 35 = 179
> 24 * 6 + 53 = 197
> 42 * 7 + 91 = 385
> 42 * 8 + 61 = 397
> 25 * 1 + 43 =  68
> 52 * 1 + 34 =  86
> 25 * 1 + 73 =  98
> 52 * 1 + 37 =  89
> 25 * 1 + 39 =  64
> 25 * 1 + 64 =  89
> 52 * 1 + 46 =  98
> 25 * 1 + 48 =  73
> 25 * 1 + 68 =  93
> 25 * 3 + 14 =  89
> 25 * 3 + 89 = 164
> 52 * 8 + 63 = 479
> 26 * 1 + 53 =  79
> 62 * 1 + 35 =  97
> 26 * 1 + 49 =  75
> 26 * 1 + 57 =  83
> 26 * 3 + 17 =  95
> 26 * 4 + 79 = 183
> 62 * 7 + 19 = 453
> 62 * 8 + 41 = 537
> 27 * 1 + 38 =  65
> 27 * 1 + 56 =  83
> 27 * 1 + 59 =  86
> 27 * 1 + 68 =  95
> 27 * 3 + 14 =  95
> 27 * 3 + 15 =  96
> 27 * 3 + 84 = 165
> 27 * 3 + 68 = 149
> 72 * 4 + 81 = 369
> 27 * 4 + 85 = 193
> 27 * 5 + 34 = 169
> 27 * 5 + 63 = 198
> 72 * 6 + 51 = 483
> 72 * 8 + 43 = 619
> 72 * 8 + 39 = 615
> 28 * 1 + 37 =  65
> 28 * 1 + 39 =  67
> 28 * 1 + 45 =  73
> 28 * 1 + 65 =  93
> 28 * 1 + 67 =  95
> 28 * 3 + 65 = 149
> 82 * 4 + 51 = 379
> 28 * 4 + 63 = 175
> 28 * 4 + 57 = 169
> 82 * 4 + 67 = 395
> 82 * 6 + 47 = 539
> 82 * 7 + 45 = 619
> 82 * 9 + 16 = 754
> 28 * 9 + 65 = 317
> 29 * 1 + 35 =  64
> 29 * 1 + 38 =  67
> 29 * 1 + 54 =  83
> 29 * 1 + 46 =  75
> 29 * 1 + 57 =  86
> 29 * 3 + 67 = 154
> 29 * 3 + 78 = 165
> 92 * 4 + 17 = 385
> 29 * 4 + 67 = 183
> 92 * 7 + 14 = 658
> 92 * 7 + 41 = 685
> 34 * 1 + 52 =  86
> 43 * 1 + 25 =  68
> 34 * 1 + 58 =  92
> 34 * 2 + 17 =  85
> 34 * 2 + 19 =  87
> 34 * 2 + 97 = 165
> 43 * 2 + 79 = 165
> 34 * 2 + 89 = 157
> 43 * 2 + 89 = 175
> 43 * 5 + 71 = 286
> 43 * 5 + 81 = 296
> 43 * 5 + 76 = 291
> 34 * 6 + 87 = 291
> 34 * 7 + 51 = 289
> 34 * 7 + 18 = 256
> 34 * 7 + 58 = 296
> 35 * 1 + 62 =  97
> 53 * 1 + 26 =  79
> 35 * 1 + 29 =  64
> 35 * 1 + 47 =  82
> 53 * 2 + 68 = 174
> 53 * 4 + 69 = 281
> 35 * 7 + 41 = 286
> 35 * 7 + 19 = 264
> 53 * 7 + 91 = 462
> 35 * 7 + 46 = 291
> 53 * 8 + 72 = 496
> 53 * 8 + 67 = 491
> 36 * 1 + 42 =  78
> 63 * 1 + 24 =  87
> 36 * 1 + 49 =  85
> 36 * 1 + 58 =  94
> 36 * 2 + 15 =  87
> 36 * 2 + 17 =  89
> 63 * 2 + 49 = 175
> 36 * 2 + 87 = 159
> 36 * 4 + 75 = 219
> 63 * 5 + 97 = 412
> 63 * 7 + 51 = 492
> 63 * 7 + 18 = 459
> 63 * 9 + 17 = 584
> 37 * 1 + 52 =  89
> 73 * 1 + 25 =  98
> 37 * 1 + 28 =  65
> 37 * 1 + 45 =  82
> 37 * 1 + 49 =  86
> 37 * 2 + 15 =  89
> 37 * 2 + 94 = 168
> 37 * 5 + 84 = 269
> 37 * 5 + 96 = 281
> 73 * 6 + 21 = 459
> 73 * 6 + 51 = 489
> 37 * 6 + 59 = 281
> 73 * 8 + 12 = 596
> 73 * 8 + 41 = 625
> 73 * 8 + 45 = 629
> 73 * 9 + 24 = 681
> 37 * 9 + 82 = 415
> 38 * 1 + 27 =  65
> 38 * 1 + 29 =  67
> 38 * 1 + 54 =  92
> 38 * 1 + 56 =  94
> 38 * 2 + 69 = 145
> 38 * 4 + 65 = 217
> 38 * 4 + 67 = 219
> 83 * 5 + 76 = 491
> 38 * 6 + 51 = 279
> 38 * 6 + 17 = 245
> 38 * 6 + 19 = 247
> 83 * 9 + 15 = 762
> 39 * 1 + 25 =  64
> 39 * 1 + 28 =  67
> 39 * 1 + 46 =  85
> 39 * 1 + 47 =  86
> 39 * 2 + 67 = 145
> 39 * 2 + 76 = 154
> 39 * 2 + 78 = 156
> 39 * 2 + 87 = 165
> 93 * 5 + 21 = 486
> 93 * 5 + 17 = 482
> 39 * 5 + 81 = 276
> 39 * 6 + 41 = 275
> 93 * 6 + 14 = 572
> 39 * 6 + 47 = 281
> 93 * 8 + 12 = 756
> 93 * 8 + 21 = 765
> 45 * 1 + 23 =  68
> 54 * 1 + 32 =  86
> 45 * 1 + 28 =  73
> 54 * 1 + 29 =  83
> 45 * 1 + 37 =  82
> 54 * 1 + 38 =  92
> 45 * 3 + 62 = 197
> 54 * 3 + 27 = 189
> 45 * 7 + 81 = 396
> 54 * 7 + 18 = 396
> 46 * 1 + 32 =  78
> 64 * 1 + 23 =  87
> 46 * 1 + 52 =  98
> 64 * 1 + 25 =  89
> 46 * 1 + 29 =  75
> 46 * 1 + 39 =  85
> 46 * 2 + 83 = 175
> 46 * 2 + 93 = 185
> 46 * 2 + 95 = 187
> 64 * 2 + 59 = 187
> 64 * 3 + 95 = 287
> 64 * 7 + 81 = 529
> 46 * 7 + 29 = 351
> 46 * 7 + 59 = 381
> 64 * 8 + 17 = 529
> 46 * 8 + 27 = 395
> 64 * 8 + 27 = 539
> 47 * 1 + 35 =  82
> 47 * 1 + 39 =  86
> 47 * 3 + 28 = 169
> 74 * 3 + 59 = 281
> 47 * 5 + 91 = 326
> 47 * 5 + 63 = 298
> 47 * 5 + 86 = 321
> 47 * 6 + 13 = 295
> 47 * 8 + 16 = 392
> 74 * 8 + 23 = 615
> 48 * 1 + 25 =  73
> 48 * 2 + 63 = 159
> 48 * 2 + 73 = 169
> 84 * 3 + 15 = 267
> 84 * 3 + 17 = 269
> 48 * 3 + 25 = 169
> 48 * 3 + 52 = 196
> 48 * 3 + 75 = 219
> 48 * 6 + 71 = 359
> 84 * 6 + 19 = 523
> 48 * 6 + 27 = 315
> 84 * 6 + 27 = 531
> 48 * 6 + 29 = 317
> 84 * 7 + 51 = 639
> 48 * 7 + 16 = 352
> 48 * 7 + 25 = 361
> 84 * 7 + 25 = 613
> 48 * 7 + 29 = 365
> 48 * 7 + 56 = 392
> 49 * 1 + 26 =  75
> 49 * 1 + 36 =  85
> 49 * 1 + 37 =  86
> 49 * 3 + 28 = 175
> 49 * 3 + 68 = 215
> 49 * 5 + 31 = 276
> 49 * 5 + 18 = 263
> 49 * 5 + 81 = 326
> 49 * 5 + 36 = 281
> 49 * 5 + 67 = 312
> 49 * 5 + 76 = 321
> 49 * 6 + 81 = 375
> 94 * 6 + 23 = 587
> 94 * 7 + 23 = 681
> 49 * 7 + 25 = 368
> 94 * 7 + 25 = 683
> 94 * 8 + 13 = 765
> 56 * 1 + 23 =  79
> 65 * 1 + 32 =  97
> 56 * 1 + 42 =  98
> 65 * 1 + 24 =  89
> 56 * 1 + 27 =  83
> 65 * 1 + 28 =  93
> 56 * 1 + 38 =  94
> 56 * 2 + 37 = 149
> 56 * 3 + 81 = 249
> 65 * 3 + 84 = 279
> 56 * 3 + 49 = 217
> 56 * 4 + 97 = 321
> 56 * 7 + 91 = 483
> 56 * 8 + 31 = 479
> 56 * 8 + 23 = 471
> 57 * 1 + 32 =  89
> 75 * 1 + 23 =  98
> 57 * 1 + 26 =  83
> 57 * 1 + 29 =  86
> 57 * 2 + 49 = 163
> 57 * 2 + 69 = 183
> 75 * 3 + 64 = 289
> 57 * 3 + 48 = 219
> 57 * 4 + 61 = 289
> 57 * 4 + 63 = 291
> 57 * 4 + 98 = 326
> 57 * 6 + 81 = 423
> 57 * 6 + 89 = 431
> 57 * 8 + 13 = 469
> 57 * 8 + 36 = 492
> 58 * 1 + 34 =  92
> 58 * 1 + 36 =  94
> 58 * 2 + 63 = 179
> 58 * 2 + 47 = 163
> 85 * 3 + 14 = 269
> 85 * 3 + 41 = 296
> 85 * 3 + 19 = 274
> 58 * 3 + 67 = 241
> 58 * 4 + 61 = 293
> 58 * 4 + 37 = 269
> 58 * 4 + 39 = 271
> 58 * 6 + 73 = 421
> 85 * 7 + 24 = 619
> 85 * 7 + 34 = 629
> 59 * 1 + 24 =  83
> 59 * 1 + 27 =  86
> 59 * 3 + 71 = 248
> 59 * 3 + 84 = 261
> 59 * 3 + 87 = 264
> 59 * 4 + 31 = 267
> 59 * 4 + 76 = 312
> 59 * 6 + 18 = 372
> 59 * 6 + 24 = 378
> 59 * 6 + 27 = 381
> 59 * 6 + 78 = 432
> 59 * 7 + 13 = 426
> 67 * 1 + 28 =  95
> 76 * 2 + 43 = 195
> 67 * 2 + 49 = 183
> 67 * 4 + 15 = 283
> 67 * 5 + 93 = 428
> 67 * 8 + 13 = 549
> 68 * 1 + 25 =  93
> 68 * 1 + 27 =  95
> 68 * 2 + 43 = 179
> 68 * 2 + 39 = 175
> 68 * 2 + 57 = 193
> 68 * 3 + 47 = 251
> 68 * 4 + 57 = 329
> 68 * 4 + 79 = 351
> 68 * 7 + 43 = 519
> 69 * 2 + 45 = 183
> 69 * 2 + 47 = 185
> 69 * 3 + 74 = 281
> 69 * 4 + 51 = 327
> 69 * 4 + 81 = 357
> 69 * 5 + 42 = 387
> 69 * 5 + 73 = 418
> 69 * 5 + 78 = 423
> 69 * 5 + 87 = 432
> 69 * 7 + 38 = 521
> 69 * 7 + 48 = 531
> 69 * 8 + 21 = 573
> 78 * 3 + 15 = 249
> 78 * 3 + 61 = 295
> 87 * 4 + 21 = 369
> 87 * 6 + 12 = 534
> 87 * 6 + 21 = 543
> 78 * 6 + 23 = 491
> 78 * 6 + 25 = 493
> 79 * 4 + 52 = 368
> 79 * 4 + 65 = 381
> 79 * 5 + 31 = 426
> 79 * 5 + 23 = 418
> 79 * 6 + 38 = 512
> 79 * 8 + 21 = 653
> 79 * 8 + 13 = 645
> 89 * 4 + 16 = 372
> 89 * 5 + 31 = 476
> 89 * 5 + 17 = 462
> 89 * 5 + 26 = 471
> 89 * 6 + 13 = 547
> 89 * 7 + 12 = 635
> 89 * 7 + 31 = 654
> ```